# Flink, where can I find the ExecutionEnvironment#readSequenceFile method?

Tags: apache-flink

I have hdfs data files which were originally created by mapreduce job with output settings like below,

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(BytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat.class);
SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job, CompressionType.BLOCK);
```

Now I'm trying to read these files with Flink DataSet API (version 1.5.6), I look into the [flink doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/), but couldn't figure out how to do that.

1. In the doc, there's an API 'readSequenceFile', I just cannot find it in the class ExecutionEnvironment, I can find 'readCsvFile', 'readTextFile', but not this one.
2. There's a general one 'readFile(inputFormat, path)', but I have no clue what's the inputFormat, it seems this API doesn't accept hadoop input format such as 'SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat'.

Could anyone please shed some light here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you missed is an additional dependency: `"org.apache.flink"   %% "flink-hadoop-compatibility" % 1.7.2`

Once you added this you can run:

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.createInput(HadoopInputs.readSequenceFile[Long, String](classOf[Long], classOf[String], "/data/wherever"))
```

Find a more detail documentation about the what and how here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/hadoop_compatibility.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, you save my day.

Comment: Hi TobiSH, I'd like to output the result to hdfs using SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat, it seems I can use HadoopOutputFormat according to the link you provided above, but it requires to initialize a mapreduce Job instance, does that mean it would internally trigger a mapreduce job?

Comment: I am not sure. I would just give it a try. You should be able to see what's happening at your job manager. Sorry.